# Is there bindN in default libraries?

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative

I wonder if there are bind2, bind3 etc kind of functions defined somewhere in standard packages?

```
bind2 :: (Monad m, Applicative m) => (a -> b -> m c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
bind2 f a b = join (liftA2 a b)
```

Why I want that? Because I'd like to reduce binds to bare minimum. For example if we are using free monad approach to build up automatically concurrent async computations, or fetches like in [Haxl](https://code.facebook.com/projects/854888367872565/haxl/):

```
fetchForSuggestions :: Artist -> [Like] -> Async [Suggestions]
fetchForSuggestions = error "implement me"

-- Two binds!
action :: ArtistId -> UserId -> Async [Suggestions]
action artistId userId = do
  artist <- fetchArtist artistId
  likes <- fetchUserLikes userId
  fetchForSuggestions artist likes

-- Single bind
-- here artist and user likes could be fetched concurrently
action :: ArtistId -> UserId -> Async [Suggestions]
action artistId userId = bind2 fetchForSuggestions (fetchArtist artistId) (fetchUserLikes userId)
```

Am I introducing some kind of anti-pattern here? Should I try to do:

```
complexAction :: ParamA -> ParamB -> ParamC -> Async Result
complexAction a b c = do
  (x, y, z) <- (,,) <$> subActionX a b <*> subActionY b c <*> subActionZ c a
  (i, j, k) <- (,,) <$> subActionI a x <*> subActionJ b y <*> subActionK c z
  finalAction i j k x y z
```

where each `subAction` function is bind-free? I.e. remove `action` taking `ArtistId` and `UserId`, and leave only `fetchForSuggestions`?

Comment: Sounds like you might benefit from `{-# LANGUAGE ApplicativeDo #-}`. :) https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ApplicativeDo

Answer (score 2):

With the [AMP](https://github.com/quchen/articles/blob/master/applicative_monad.md) you should be able to just write `f <$> a <*> b`, where `f :: (Applicative m) => a -> b -> c`, and `a :: (Applicative m) => m a` and `b :: (Applicative m) m b`. Since the AMP went through (as of September 2014,) in GHC Head, you can actually do that now! Your code becomes:

```
action artistId userId =
  join (fetchForSuggestions <$> fetchArtist artistId <*> fetchUserLikes userId)
```

This will work for any Monad in GHC Head right now, I think it will also work for 7.8.3, and it will most assuredly work in 7.10.

The neat thing is that this is general. For any n-ary action `k :: a_1 -> ... -> a_n -> m c`, you can write

```
join (k <$> (x_1 :: a_1) <*> ... <*> (x_n :: a_n)) :: m c
```

In general, though, this notation isn't terribly better than just using multiple `do` binds. I think you'd have to carefully consider which one would be more readable. Using multiple binds is not an antipattern, and happens quite often, in fact. A `bind2` etc. is pretty much made unnecessary by `do` syntax, and I don't think it exists.

Comment: In `f <$> x <*> y`, `f` is of type `a -> b -> c` usually. You are missing a `join` I need.

Comment: You are right of course. That's what I get for just quickly throwing together an answer at work :-P

Comment: `do { a <- ma; b <- mb; f a b }` has two `>>=` when desugared. For me it's important to have as less binds as possible. I'd rewrite it into `do { (a, b) <- (,) <$> ma <*> mb; f a b }` or `join (f <$> ma <*> mb)` as you proosed, yet `bind2 f ma mb` is much more readable IMHO. ApplicativeDo will solve this problem, but it's not here yet.

Comment: Why is it so important to have as few binds as possible? If performance is your concern, then *all* the alternatives (including `join` + `fmap` + `<*>`, as well as your `bind2`, because `liftA2` does exactly the same) aren't going to fare much better. (Though you shouldn't take my word for it, but benchmark it with criterion.) If "code elegance" is your objective, I don't think multiple binds are frowned upon, or in any way stylistically bad.

Comment: Check https://code.facebook.com/posts/302060973291128/open-sourcing-haxl-a-library-for-haskell/ for a reason why I want as few binds as possible.